# Make Tkinter Frame Fill Vertical Axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this code:

```
self.master= master
self.master.title('Student Tracker')
self.master.configure(bg='#007534')
self.photo = PhotoImage(file = 'Logo.gif')
self.SchoolLogo = Label(self.master, image = self.photo,bg = 'white').grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=W+E)
mainFrame = Frame(self.master).grid(sticky=N+E+S+W)
leftSide = Frame(mainFrame,bg='#007534').grid(sticky=N+E+S+W,row=1,column=0,rowspan=5)
rightSide=Frame(mainFrame,bg='#A8D59D').grid(row=1,column=1,rowspan=5,sticky=N+E+S+W)
welcomeLabel= Label(leftSide,text='Welcome', fg='white',bg='#007534').grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=N)
welcome2=Label(rightSide,text='Hello',fg='Black').grid(row=2,column=1)
attendanceBtn=Button(leftSide,text='Attendance',command=self.attendance,bg='white',fg='#007534').grid(row=3,column=0)
gradeBtn=Button(leftSide,text='Grades',command=self.attendance,bg='white',fg='#007534').grid(row=4,column=0)
self.master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.master.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=4)
```

which produces this layout: [image: Layout]

But I want the frames to fill the vertical axis too. But when I try using `.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)`

I get this Second Layout: [image: Second Layout]

which looks distorted. Is there anyway to expand the frame, but make the widgets look organized?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example to help you. It is just about playing with the positioning and using `grid_rowconfigure()`, `grid_columnconfigure()` in the right *containers*.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg='#007534')
mainFrame = tk.Frame(root).grid(sticky="nsew")
leftSide = tk.Frame(mainFrame, bg='#007534')
leftSide.grid(sticky="nsew", row=0, column=0)
rightSide = tk.Frame(mainFrame, bg='#A8D59D')
rightSide.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
tk.Label(leftSide,text='Welcome', fg='white',bg='#007534').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="n")
tk.Label(rightSide,text='Hello',fg='Black').grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Button(leftSide,text='Attendance', bg='white', fg='#007534').grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(leftSide,text='Grades', bg='white', fg='#007534').grid(row=2, column=0)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=4)
leftSide.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
rightSide.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

In the end I should remind you that all your variables like *mainFrame*, *leftSide*, *rightSide* and the labels are `None` (which is the return value of `grid()`). Do correct them, you may face issues later on.